# Excel - max between 2 series

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

I have 2 series of data. For sake of simplicity, lets say the data looks like below,

set 1:

```
1   3
2   3.5
3   4
4   4.5
5   5
6   5.5
7   6
8   6.5
9   7
10  7.5
```

set 2:

```
1.5   2
2.8   4.5
3.5   8
4.5   6
5.5   4.8
6.5   4
7.5   6.5
8.5   9
9.5   3
10.5  4
```

After charting these 2 sets, I want to get the line with the higher data. I want the black line, In the attached pic. How do I get that? My actual data has thousands of data points, so doing this manually isn't possible.

Added later: Another thing I forgot to mention, in my actual data 1 set has about 500 x,y values, and the other set has about 50 values. Though the end points have same/similar x values. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: As per request from other users, could you upload or send the excel sheet (dropbox or similar), if you don't think the existing answer is satisfying. Thanks :)!

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. Also do you mean the simplified excel sheet or my actual one? Thanks. Also thanks for editing my original question. I had no clue how to format it.

Comment: "the simplified excel sheet or my actual one?" <-- yes

Answer (score 2):

Given your information about the chart and the tables, I would do something like this:

The new series will be based on two formulas:

In Column H, I have the formula for the max value (between your two series):

```
=MAX(B2,E2)
```

In Column G, I have the formula that based on the Max value (formula above), which X value I should use (X-value from Series 1 or 2).

```
=IF(H2=B2,A2,D2)
```

[image]

Then I can plot my graph:

- Series 1, Column B
- Series 2, Column E
- Series 3, Column H.
- All series uses the X values of Column G.

Comment: While this isn't exact, I think this is the right way to go. Trying to determine the intersection of the two lines to flatten that `max` line in some of those corners is going to be quite a feat.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue with this approach is it bumps up intermediate points. For example, for the x-value of 2, the y value becomes ~3.8 instead of 3.5. Also I need the x,y value at the intersections if possible. Hopefully, I made sense. Thanks.

Comment: In order to find the x/y intersection of the line you will have to convert both line segments (the two x/y values of both series that make up the begin and end of those segments) into their `y=mx+b` form so you can get the slope and y-intercept. Then with that you can determine the x/y intersection of the two segments with some really ugly formulas. Then you'll have to determine for that `x intercept` which `y` value is the max (your series one at that same point using it's `y=mx+b`, your second series using it's `y=mx+b` or your `y-intercept`. I think you'll find this answer "Close enough"

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying. But I don't think I can actually do it :(.

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction**

A few assumptions/comments/pitfalls/constraints regarding my solution:

- Set 1 and Set 2 are in columns A till D.
- The combined data set will combine the x-values of both Sets, and will have additional data points where the lines cross.
- It involves several helper columns, in particular to allow you to copy/paste this across multiple worksheet with data.
- I did not try to condense too much, to improve readability, and probably some helper columns could be combined.
- It was tested with the data set from the question, but difficult to guarantee all "boundary" conditions, e.g. identical data points between Set 1 and Set 2, zero overlap between the two data sets, empty data sets, etc. (I did test some of these, see my comments at the end).
- Set 1 and Set 2 must be sorted (on x-values). If this is not the case, a few additional helper columns are needed to sort the data dynamically.

To better understand the solution described below, see herewith the resulting graph, based on the data set in the question (although I added one data point [2.5;3.75] to avoid having the data points of Set 1 and Set 2 perfectly alternating):

[image]

**General solution outline / methodology**

- Combine both datasets in a single (sorted) column;
- For all x-values, determine highest y-value, between the y-value in the Set, and the calculated y-value on the line segment from the neighboring values in the other Set (looks simple, in particular with the given example data set, but this is quite tricky to do when data sets have no alternating x-values);
- Find the points (x & y values) where the lines of the graph are crossing (intersecting), let's call this Set 3
- Combine and sort (on x-values) the three data sets in a two columns (for x & y values).

**The details and formulas**

For the formulas, I assume row 1 contains headings, and the data start on row 2. All formulas should be entered in row 2, except for a few, where I mention to put them in row 3 (because they need data from the preceding row). The result is in columns E (x-values) and F (y-values), and G till AG are helper columns).

- Column E : `=INDEX(AH$2:AH$30;MATCH(ROWS(AH$2:AH2);$AJ$2:$AJ$30;0))` These is the actual result. Gets all x-values in AH and sorts these based on an index column AJ; this should actually be the last column in the logical flow, but for presentation purposes it is cleaner to have this next to the input data sets;
- F : `=INDEX(AF$2:AF$30;MATCH(ROWS(AF$2:AF2);$AG$2:$AG$30;0))` Same for y-values;
- G : `=IF(ISNA(H2);NA();COUNTIF($H$2:$H$30;"<="&H2))` Creates index to sort combined x-values of both data sets. You also can dynamically sort without such helper column, but then you need a `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` and with long decimal numbers I have some bad experiences with these;
- H : `=IF(ROW()-1<=COUNT($A$2:$A$30);A2;IF((ROW()-1)<=(COUNT($A$2:$A$30)+COUNT($C$2:$C$30));INDEX($C$2:$C$30;ROW()-COUNT($A$2:$A$30)-1;1);NA()))` Combines x-values of both data sets, i.e. in columns A & C;
- I : `=IF(ROW()-1<=COUNT($B$2:$B$30);B2;IF((ROW()-1)<=(COUNT($B$2:$B$30)+COUNT($D$2:$D$30));INDEX($D$2:$D$30;ROW()-COUNT($B$2:$B$30)-1;1);NA()))` Same for the y-values;
- J : `=IF(ROW()-1<=COUNT($A$2:$A$30);"S1";IF((ROW()-1)<=(COUNT($A$2:$A$30)+COUNT($C$2:$C$30));"S2";NA()))` Assign "S1", or "S2" to each data point, as indication from which data set they come;
- K : `=IF(J2=J3;INTERCEPT(I2:I3;H2:H3);NA())` Determines the intercept of the line segment starting at that data point;
- L : `=IF(J2=J3;SLOPE(I2:I3;H2:H3);NA())` Same for slope;
- M : `=INDEX(H$2:H$30;MATCH(ROWS(H$2:H2);$G$2:$G$30;0))` Sorts all x-values;
- N : `=INDEX(I$2:I$30;MATCH(ROWS(I$2:I2);$G$2:$G$30;0))` Same for y-values
- O : `=INDEX(J$2:J$30;MATCH(ROWS(J$2:J2);$G$2:$G$30;0))` Same for corresponding "S1/S2" value to indicate from which data set they come;
- P : `=INDEX(K$2:K$30;MATCH(ROWS(K$2:K2);$G$2:$G$30;0))` Same for intercept;
- Q : `=INDEX(L$2:L$30;MATCH(ROWS(L$2:L2);$G$2:$G$30;0))` Same for slope;
- R : `=IF(O2="S1";"S2";"S1")` Inversion between S1 & S2.
- S : `{=IFERROR(INDEX($O$2:$Q2;MAX(IF($O$2:$O2=$R3;ROW($O$2:$O2)-ROW(INDEX($O$2:$O2;1;1))+1));2);NA())}` **Array formula to be put in cell S3** (hence ctrl+shift+enter) that will search for the intercept of the preceding data point of the *other* data set.
- T : `{=IFERROR(INDEX($O$2:$Q2;MAX(IF($O$2:$O2=$R3;ROW($O$2:$O2)-ROW(INDEX($O$2:$O2;1;1))+1));3);NA())}` Same for slope;
- U : `=IF(OR(ISNA(N2);NOT(ISNUMBER(S2)));NA();M2*T2+S2)` Calculates the y-value on the line segment of the other data set;
- V : `=MAX(IFNA(U2;N2);N2)` Maximum value between the original y-value and the calculated y-value on the corresponding line segment of the other data set;
- W : `=(V2=N2)` Checks whether the y-value comes from the original data set or not;
- X : `=IF(O2="S1";IF(W2;"S1";"S2");IF(W2;"S2";"S1"))` Determines on which data set (line) the y-value sits (S1 or S2);
- Y : `=IFERROR(AND((X2<>X3);COUNTIF(X3:$X$30;X2)>0);FALSE)` Determines when the data sets cross (i.e. the lines on the graph intersect);
- Z : `=IF(Y2;(S2-P2)/(Q2-T2);NA())` Calculates x-value of intersection;
- AA : `=IF(Y2;Z2*Q2+P2;NA())` Calculates y-value of intersection;
- AB : `=COUNTIF($Z$2:$Z$30;"<="&Z2)` Index to sort the newly calculated intersection points (I sort them because then the combining with the other data sets is straightforward, re-using formula of column H;
- AC : `=INDEX(Z$2:Z$30;MATCH(ROWS(Z$2:Z2);$AB$2:$AB$30;0))` Sorted x-values of intersection points;
- AD : `=INDEX(AA$2:AA$30;MATCH(ROWS(AA$2:AA2);$AB$2:$AB$30;0))` Same for y-values;
- AE : `=IF(ROW()-1<=COUNT(M$2:M$30);M2;IF((ROW()-1)<=(COUNT(M$2:M$30)+COUNT(AC$2:AC$30));INDEX(AC$2:AC$30;ROW()-COUNT(M$2:M$30)-1;1);NA()))` Combine x-values of Set 1, Set 2, and the intersection points;
- AF : `=IF(ROW()-1<=COUNT(V$2:V$30);V2;IF((ROW()-1)<=(COUNT(V$2:V$30)+COUNT(AD$2:AD$30));INDEX(AD$2:AD$30;ROW()-COUNT(V$2:V$30)-1;1);NA()))` Same for y-values;
- AG : `=IF(ISNA(AE2);NA();COUNTIF($AE$2:$AE$30;"<="&AE2))` Create index to sort the resulting data set (and this is used to calculate the final results in columns E & F;

All formulas go until row 30, but this need to be changed of course based on the actual data sets. The idea is to add these formulas to one worksheet, and then columns  E > AG can be copied to all other worksheets. There are obviously quite a few `#NA` values, but this is on purpose, and are not errors or mistakes. On request, I can share the actual spreadsheet, so you do not have to retype all formulas.

**Some additional comments**

- You have to modify some formulas (the sort indices) if there are identical x-values, either within Set 1 (which I will not cover here, as it seems this would be unlikely, or be data input errors), or between Set 1 and Set 2. The dynamic sorting does not work in that case. A workaround is to create a "synthetic" sort column, e.g. with `=TEXT(J2;"0000.00000000000")&L2`. This formats all numbers the same way as text, and appends S1 or S2. So this should give unique sort values, which would sort the same way as the corresponding numbers.
- Empty data sets or data sets with only 1 value are not treated correctly either (the intercept formulas and finding values for the "previous" data point are meaningless in these cases).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, there is no restriction on helper columns. I don't mind some manual copy-pasting/sorting, however I have about 200 tabs each having these 2 data sets.
Also the x values in the 2 data sets are different. I do not really need step 5, but its good to know how to do it.

Comment: @redclip Are these 200 worksheets structures exactly the same ? So you could select all tabs, and do the manipulations for all tabs at the same time ?

Comment: the data sets in each tab have different number of x,y values. For example set 1 in tab 1 may have 500 values whereas in tab 2 it might have 300 values. Same for set 2.

Comment: And you would also have to make 200 graphs ? That's lot of work indeed to do manually. Maybe VBA would be more appropriate ?

Comment: No, I do not need graphs. I made the sample graph just for explanation. I need the max data points among the two sets.

Comment: How well are Set 1 and Set 2 "identifiable" on each worksheet? e.g. is Set 1 in columns A & B, and Set 2 in C & D? or are both sets one under the other in columns A & B (like your example data set in your question? and if so, how are they separated ? and overall, is there much other text / data / numbers on these worksheets, or is it very clean ?

Comment: I can structure the spreadsheet anyway i like. As of not set 1 is in column A&B and set 2 is in C&D. there is currently no other data or text on these sheets.

Comment: Ok, that simplifies the mechanics. Another question about the number of data points. Easiest to explain with an example of your data set. Let's take the first point of Set 2 (1.5;2). In your combined/resulting "Max" data set, do you want that data-point to appear, i.e. same x-value, but calculated y-value (on the segment of the Set 1 data points). On a line graph you would not see the point of course, but maybe you have a preference on how this should be treated in the combined set ?